# How should I get the subarray with maximum sum?

Tags: python

The question is about leetcode 53. I extend the question a little bit to return the subarray that has the maximum sum.

For example, for `list = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]` I should get `max_subarray = [4,-1,2,1]`.

My code is attached below. The result I got is `[4,-1,2,1,-5,4]`, which is the `cur_array`. I don't know what I did wrong.

```
def maxSubarray(self, list):

    cur_sum = 0
    max_sum = list[0]
    max_subarray = []
    cur_array = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        cur_sum += list[i]
        cur_array.append(list[i])
        if max_sum < cur_sum:
            max_subarray = cur_array
            max_sum = cur_sum

        if cur_sum < 0:
            cur_sum = 0
            cur_array.clear()
    return max_subarray
```

It always gives me the `cur_array`. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Never use `list` as a variable name in Python.  Doing so blocks the builtin with that name,  which is basically shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s my solution to the original question that beat 99.73%. What you need to do is track the index `i` for which the max sum is obtained. Starting from that index, you can easily find the subarray that has the sum equal to max sum.

```
import sys

class Solution:
    def maxSubArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        s = 0
        max_sum = -sys.maxsize
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            s = nums[i] + (s if s > 0 else 0)        
            max_sum = max(max_sum, s)
            
        return max_sum
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to return the subarray, not just the sum.

Comment: @Alvin666 I’ve explained in my answer how to find the subarray. I didn’t provide made-to-order code because I don’t believe in spoonfeeding.